# Displaying UISearchbarResult in the same place as my tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

This is my controller :

[image]
<sub>(source: [zupimages.net](http://www.zupimages.net/up/14/37/zcqu.png))</sub>

So I have a map view at the top, the uisearchbar at the middle et a uitableview at the bottom.

So If I use uisearchbar and display results on its table view, the tableview will be displayed in full screen, that's say over the map view and tableview and also the uisearchbar, so we will see nothing.

What I want is to display the results view in the same place as my uitableview. I tried to resize, change frame but nothing works.

Someone have any idea to resolve it or better, give me another solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 8, `UISearchController` can use your tableView to display its search results.

See the Results in Searched Controller option in Apple's [UICatalog sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html).